# What is the time complexity of T(n) = (T(n-1) + n!)?

Tags: math, time-complexity, big-o, recurrence

> Let function F is recursive and has running time of F(k) is T(k).
>
> F(k) calls F(k-1) once, and does operations which run in O(n!)
>
> F(0) is a base case, and it runs in constant time.

In my honest opinion,
I thought that `T(n) = T(0) + (1! + 2! + ... + n!)`so
it would be `T(n) <= (n! + n! + ... + n!) for n >=1`.
thus `O((n+1)!)`.

but I cannot be sure that this is enough bound.
is it a enough analysis? and Is there any method I can test?
(this algorithm is not quite practical but of curiosity.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a nice closed-form for the sum of factorials (the [exact answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227551/sum-k-1-2-3-cdots-n-is-there-a-generic-formula-for-this) is messy).

However, we can use induction to prove that 0! + 1! + 2! + ... + n! ≤ 2n!:

- Base cases: 0! ≤ 2 · 0!, 0! + 1! ≤2 · 1!, 0! + 1! + 2! ≤ 2 · 2!
- Induction: 0! + 1! + ... + k! + (k+1)! ≤ 2k! + (k+1)! ≤ (k+1)k! + (k+1)! = 2(k+1)!

So your recurrence is bounded from above by 2n! and from below by n!, meaning that the tightest bound you can get is to say that the recurrence solves to Θ(n!).

Comment: Isn't it Θ((n+1)!)

Comment: @willywonka_dailyblah I believe the proof I outlined shows that 0! + 1! + ... + n! <= 2n!, which gives a tighter bound of Theta(n!). Or am I mistaken?

Comment: I agree with induction steps. Its very delightful.

Comment: oh sorry I see, yore rite

Comment: @kaya3 To clarify, the proof bounds the sum from above by 2(n!) and from below by n!, which is where the Theta(n!) comes from. I agree that this isn’t the same as Theta((n+1)!), and the idea behind this answer was to prove that the OP’s original bound wasn’t tight.

Comment: My mistake, I misread your answer. Sorry!